# Changing main activity on Android studio java

Tags: java, android

i have `Home.java` and `Home2.java` which is the ex `MainActivity.java`. The problem is i need to start my app with `home.java` but if i change the file name in `AndroidManifest.xml` the app crash giving me no errors.

```java
        <activity android:name=".Home2" />        
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

the `.Home` file:

```java
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton fab_Add=findViewById(R.id.fab_add);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        fab_Add=findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
        fab_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openNewActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openNewActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

i tried swapping only file name and with the other one everything is good but its not what i have to do. thx for help (i'm to java)

error lines are so many, i post some of them

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dnd/com.example.dnd.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference.
at com.example.dnd.Home.<init>(Home.java:14)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the contents of the error message and stacktrace you get from logcat when it crashes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is line 14 of Home.java? The error message says you need to start here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FloatingActionButton fab_Add=findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
```

The problem is here. You cannot initialize a component field directly by calling `findViewById()`. Instead, you must call `findViewById()` in `onCreate()` or another appropriate method.

I recommend that you read a tutorial about the Activity Lifecycle in order to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

Every activity must be present in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and it automatically gets added whenever you create new Activity.
To start your app with different activity than it usually does, you just need to simply place

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

in the tags of the activity from which you want your app to start.
And if you want to change the activity name do so by right clicking on the activity in the projects tab then go to refractor then rename.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8fWd.png)

Comment: i already did everything you wrote. that's why i not understand what i'm missing.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dnd/com.example.dnd.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).